# How to show Old values of edited fields on update

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am sending the record for approval if any of the user edits, My requirement is i need to show the Old values which are edited to the approver,

I tried using process builder its not happening, Please let me know Any ideas to achieve this with out code.

Comment: You've tagged this question with `formula` and `formula-field`, but I don't see how either of those are relevant to your question. Can you explain why you've used these tags?

Comment: My first thought is that there isn't a way to avoid writing apex/visualforce for this. Field History Tracking feels like the most natural fit here, but would require you to develop a visualforce page (and a controller/extension) to use instead of the normal approval page. Can you go into more detail about why you're avoiding code here?